# How do I add delay to hover on a side menu?

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
    <div id="pastIssuesBody">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">2017</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">January</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/index.php?month=Jan&year=2017">Issue I</a></li>
                <li><a href="/index.php?month=Jan_second_issue&year=2017">Issue II</a></li>
            </ul>
```

This is my CSS:

```
    #pastIssuesBody ul {
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        width: inherit;
        font-size: 11.5pt;
    }
    #pastIssuesBody ul > li {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 11.5pt;
    }
    #pastIssuesBody li > ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        top: 0;
        display: none;
    }
    #pastIssuesBody ul > li > a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #58595b;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 8px;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #pastIssuesBody ul > li > a:hover {
        background-color:#f6f6f6;
    }
    #pastIssuesBody li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
    #pastIssuesBody ul > li > ul > li > ul {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 41px;
        display: none;
    }
```

How can I make it so that when I hover on the dates that there is a slight delay? (When I have over the year the month appears)
This is my website: https://today.byu.edu

Comment: "Here is my website - and good luck finding the code I need help with" ? - please create a [mcve] in the question it-self.

Comment: Please remember to keep your code MCVE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Just out of curiosity - without seeing any demo I have to ask, why you need a delay?

Comment: I need a delay because the client asked that when the user scrolls over the menu that it doesn't disappear so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Turns out that display cannot be animated like that. So I changed the code so that it is opacity that is changed.

```
#pastIssuesBody li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}
#pastIssuesBody ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 41px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}
#pastIssuesBody li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

EDIT:
Ok so this code had a bug that cause the other elements to show up when I scrolled over the the area. Hope that makes sense. I just changed everything to visibility instead of display. Everything works beautifully now.

Comment: Additionally, you can add a `transition-delay:.5s` to get an actual delay before the transition starts.